# Remove ttsvr in tooltwist workbench

Tags: tomcat, tooltwist

Is it also possible to remove or disable the ttsvr in my local Tooltwist8 workbench? This mean that page should load even without /ttsvr on my address bar. I'm configuring some urlrewrite.xml and I want to test it directly in my local machine. To do this, I need to disable the ttsvr so that url will only have /n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by editing 3 things.

a. **server.xml**
 - on the bottom part, duplicate context tag and change the path to "/". This would look something like this:

```
<Context docBase="ttsvr" path="/ttsvr" reloadable="false" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ttsvr"/>
<Context docBase="ttsvr" path="/" reloadable="false" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ttsvr"/>
```

b. **tooltwist.conf**
 - remove the value of <webappPrefix>/ttsvr</webappPrefix>

```
<webappPrefix></webappPrefix>
```

c. **Tomcat configuration**

- Under server options, uncheck "Serve modules without publishing".
- Under publishing, choose "Automatically publish when resources change".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Which server.xml are you referring here, the one in Servers project found in eclipse or the one found in Tomcat folder?

Comment: if you are running tooltwist v8, it is found in this path /tooltwist/tooltwist_osx_8.0/devel/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config/server.xml.

To answer your question, it is under Servers project.